# Tachometer/Speedometer drop to zero and engine wont accelerate

Tags: electrical, ford, speedometer, tachometer

today my car had the following problem:
I was driving with about 80 km/h (ca. 50 mph) when suddenly my Motor didn't react to the gas-penal anymore and I wasn't able to accelerate.
The tachometer and the speedometer dropped to zero, while I was still driving. The kilometer display wasn't showing anything anymore. 
Additional to that all lights showed up.

[image: image of the tachometer]

The engine didn't shut down and was still running on idle (even uphill in the second gear). After a short time, the error disappeared again. But it kept coming back regularly.

The error comes together with a bundle of error-logs which are:

- [P1935](https://obdii.pro/de/code/P1935)
- [P1936](https://www.obd-data.com/p1936.html)
- [P193B](https://obdii.pro/de/code/P193B)
- [P2584](https://obdii.pro/de/code/P2584)

Three of them relate to signals/sensors. Therefore, I guess that it's an electrical error. But I have no clue what could be causing it.

The Car is a Ford Focus Tunier 1.6 tcdi diesel 109 PS constructed in 2006 and it has about 156.000 km / 97000 miles

Comment: The error codes make sense, but what does "no longer accepts gas" mean? If it's idling, then it's using gas...

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback :) The engine didn't react to the gas-pedal anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on Hilux where rev counter dropped and battery and auto transmission temp level lit up whilst driving. Took battery in to check - it was flat and after a recharge, tested good. Took alternator off and got it tested - was also fine. Put it all back together and had it tested - still fine. Only happened intermittently and when vehicle was hot, i.e. highway driving. It was a high resistance corroded connection on the battery terminal. One connector was slightly concave. Took a file and filed it clean and flat and error was fixed.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a Rabbit GTI that did that. It was the Hall effect sensor in the distributor. The engine would flatline. Very sporadically. I had a 94 Audi 90 that would do that, but I lost every light in/on the car. Always in a blizzard. I loved those cars. Moving from VW to Audi was an adju$tment. The quattro with 5-sped diff lock makes me want to make a pot of soup to capture my tears.